# Python module returning True

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing Python for a kind of computer, and the login module always returns true, even if it's not in the `users` dictionary:

```
cur_user = "null"
users = {
    "Splavacado100": "20310"
}

def login():
    good_login = 0
    user_name = raw_input("Enter your username: ")
    for user in users:
        if user == user_name:
            good_login = 1
    if good_login == 1:
        user_password = raw_input("Enter your password: ")
        if users[user_name] == user_password:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return "None"

def OS():
    log_att = False
    log_att = login()
    if log_att:
        print "True"
    else:
        print "False"

OS()
```

How can I make it return false in those cases?

I am using Python 2.7.10.

Comment: You have a dictionary. You shouldn't need to iterate over all the keys to check the user exists

Comment: Please state your question

Comment: The code will return `True` even if I enter something not in the `users` dictionary, like "hi".

Comment: You have two inputs. You'd have to enter more than "hi" to get the function to return anything but False, None, or "None"

Comment: If you have an answer, please modify my code and answer the question with it.

Comment: Dicts are hash maps, which, by definion you can query with `.get("user")` which can be evaluated with `if`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something wrong with your second method. I took it out and the first part works. I then took out the last else in the first method and seems to work. Try [this](https://repl.it/DcBH)

```
cur_user = "null"
users = {
    "Splavacado100": "20310"
}
def login():
    good_login = 0
    user_name = raw_input("Enter your username: ")
    for user in users:
        if user == user_name:
            good_login = 1
    if good_login == 1:
        user_password = raw_input("Enter your password: ")
        if users[user_name] == user_password:
            return True
        else:
            return False
def OS():
    log_att = False
    log_att = login()
     if log_att:
        print "True"
    else:
        print "False"
OS()
```

Comment: Your the only person one this thread who understands this question, but fix your whitespace, especially for Python.

Comment: @TyStaszak yeah sorry hit enter earlier than expected :)

Comment: And you're right. `login` returning `None` confused the `if` statement.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of returning "None", return None (as "None" is always true as it is a non-zero value).

Comment: True. `"None"` is a string which is inherently `True`.  `None` is inherently `False`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your login function should look more like;

```
def login():
    raw_user = raw_input("Enter your username: ")
    password = users.get(raw_user)
    if not password:
        return False
    raw_password = raw_input("Enter your password: ")
    if password == raw_password:
        return True
    return False
```

Then your second function can be simplified:

```
def OS():
    if login():
        print "True"
    else:
        print "False"
```